# OpenERP add column to treeView

Tags: python, xml, field, odoo

Im trying to show new column in treeview purchase.order.tree.

My goal is, becosue i have only product, all my orders have only one product with quantity number, so how to show this quantity in treeview purchase.order.tree ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override the original view and add the new field, like on this example overriding account.invoice:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="new_invoice_tree">
        <field name="name">mymodule.account.invoice.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position="after">
                <field name="quantity"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

just make sure that inherit_id is referencing the original view and you set the correct model on name="model"

Comment: hi thank you for info, and can i ask you how will looks like a code in py file?